# How to block all .tk domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, block

I want to block all referral from .tk , .gl , .ml domains i write this code blow but not worked for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(.*)?\.(cc|eu|ru|xyz|online|ml|gl|tk)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

Help to fix it.

Comment: That pattern would block many more requests than desired if it would get applied. `(/.*)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: This probably is what you are looking for: `https?://[^/]+\.(cc|eu|ru|xyz|online|ml|gl|tk)\.[^/]+/`